# Hide Published text from custom post types column

Tags: custom-post-types, columns

Is it possible to hide the 'Published' word only on custom post types column? as in image and just leave the date and time?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress has a filter for that..

```
function wpse406965_remove_status( $status, $post, $column_name, $mode ) {
    
    //Get the post type. Replace YOUR_CPT with your CPT slug.
    if ( $post->post_type == 'YOUR_CPT' ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $status;
}
add_filter( 'post_date_column_status', 'wpse406965_remove_status', 10, 4);
```

Comment: Hello Abhik Perfect that worked excellent :)

Comment: @jamesnelson82 could you please accept this as the answer? Will be helpful for future visitors to find it.

Comment: hey Abhik I just have thank you could you take a look at this please https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/406970/custom-post-type-hide-or-disable-the-status-line-in-publish-meta-box