# custom post type, hide or disable the status line in publish meta box

Tags: custom-taxonomy, post-status

I have been adding a post type to my theme, how do I hide/disable the status line (All of it) as in image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress doesn't provide any filter/hook to override the existing HTML in post submit metabox. So, either you remove the entire metabox and add your own (which will be overkill in your case) or just hide it using CSS or remove that element using JS.

```
function wpse406970_remove_publishing_actions() {
    global $typenow;
    if ( $typenow == 'YOUR_CPT' ) { ?>
        <style>
            .misc-pub-post-status {
                display: none !important;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                $('.misc-pub-post-status').remove();
            });
        </script>   
    <?php }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpse406970_remove_publishing_actions', 999 );
```

I recommend using both approaches as only JS might show a spalsh of the element before removing.

Comment: Hey Abhik I added to css and that did not hide it can you help?

Comment: @jamesnelson82 Check now.

Comment: Hey Abhik I added JS but the code remove EVERYTHING in that box apart from 'Move to bin' and 'Update' button    -      these are divs  id="misc-publishing-actions" , class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-post-status"

Comment: @jamesnelson82 My bad. I targeted the wrong element. Should work now.

Comment: hey Abhik yes this works but when I reload the page the whole status line appears

Comment: @jamesnelson82 It shouldn't. The JS removes the element after the DOM is ready in every pageload. Anyway, I edited my answer and included the CSS to be printed too. Please check.

Comment: Good Morning Abhik just added your code, and it works perfectly, Thank you very much :)